# Raspberry Pi not booting up

Tags: boot

While trying to configure I2C in my Raspberry Pi, I issued the command sudo shutdown -r now.

Since  then my Raspberry Pi is not starting up. Any help on how to start my Pi would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try unplug power adapter then plug ?

Comment: Yes I did upnplug the power adapter... but it did not work :(

Comment: Please look at http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Power_.2F_Start-up and compare your LEDs status with LED statuses table. Also there are many situation which can help you to understand why it's not booting. Is RPi connected screen/monitor/TV ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improper shutdown, now 3 flashes on boot](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4233/improper-shutdown-now-3-flashes-on-boot)

Comment: Please do not sign your questions with "Thanks". Consider taking a minute to read the [About Page](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/about). You should give thanks to people by upvoting their answers. If an answer helps you solve your problem please accept it. I have edited your question to improve its quality. Feel free to edit and rephrase as you like.

Answer (score 1):

No real info about the problem, and probably a duplicate question...

try connection the RPI to a monitor/tv and reading the gurcanozturk link to do some basic debug and add more information. Also try to read this [other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7489/recover-files-from-broken-sd-card-no-boot/7508#7508) for the most common SD problems.